# transfer windows retail licence to a new computer when the old computer dies and i can not run `slmgr` command to deactivate licence on old computer

Tags: windows-10, license

Can I transfer windows retail licence to a new computer when the old computer having digital licence dies and i can not run `slmgr puk` command to deactivate licence on old computer which is dead.

Edit I have purchased full package retail product key from amazon with installation media

Comment: Get the new computer with a new Windows 10 OEM license. The old OEM license dies with the old computer. It seems to me unlikely you would have a Retail License (with email receipt and key) but Retail can be transferred.

Comment: Given the License is Full Retail, you can transfer it without issue. You need the email from Amazon that will have the license key. You may need to call Microsoft Licensing Support to activate since the old computer is dead.

Comment: its a packaged box with media and activation key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 Full Retail Licenses can be transferred from one computer to another.

In this case, the old computer is dead.

Set up the new computer, install Windows and attempt to activate. If it does, great. If not, use the screens to contact Microsoft Licensing Support and explain that the old computer died.

They will help you and kill the old license so that you can activate.

Good luck.